Unable to connect to my vps through ssh using PublicKeys
I'm new to system administration and I am trying to setup (/secure) my first VPS. To my understanding using Keys are "safer" than using passwords, so here I am trying to do just that.
I've tried a few things before writing this post:

I tried generating a key ON my VPS server using ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096
Afterwards I did cp /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub /root/.ssh/authorized_keys id_rsa.pub
I then copied the contents of the private key using cat /root/.ssh/id_rsa and imported it on BitVise.

I also tried the other way around, I generated the key on BitVise and then did the exact process but in reverse. Copied the public key onto my SSH server.
Finally I tried to use PuTTY thinking perhaps it's a BitVise issue, but no, still getting denied...
More things I have tried:

Set PermitRootLogin back to yes and attempted to login with root using the key, didn't work.
Copied the public key from /root/.ssh/authorized_keys/id_rsa.pub to my my user's home directory /home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys/id_rsa.pub, couldn't login using my key with my user account

Every time I made a change to the the config file I would reboot or sudo systemctl restart ssh and sudo systemctl restart sshd
Additional information:

I ran apt update & apt upgrade before doing the things I mentioned above
I am able to login using passwords, just not keys...
I double checked and my id_rsa.pub is located @ /root/.ssh/authorized_keys and the contents are there

Ubuntu Version: Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-174-generic x86_64)
Here is my /etc/ssh/sshd_config:
#       $OpenBSD: sshd_config,v 1.103 2018/04/09 20:41:22 tj Exp $

# This is the sshd server system-wide configuration file.  See
# sshd_config(5) for more information.

# This sshd was compiled with PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

# The strategy used for options in the default sshd_config shipped with
# OpenSSH is to specify options with their default value where
# possible, but leave them commented.  Uncommented options override the
# default value.

#Include /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/*.conf

Port XXXXX
#AddressFamily any
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
#ListenAddress ::

#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key

# Ciphers and keying
#RekeyLimit default none

# Logging
#SyslogFacility AUTH
#LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:

LoginGraceTime 2m
StrictModes yes
MaxAuthTries 6
MaxSessions 10

PubkeyAuthentication yes

# Expect .ssh/authorized_keys2 to be disregarded by default in future.
AuthorizedKeysFile      .ssh/authorized_keys .ssh/authorized_keys2

#AuthorizedPrincipalsFile none

#AuthorizedKeysCommand none
#AuthorizedKeysCommandUser nobody

# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
#HostbasedAuthentication no
# Change to yes if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for
# HostbasedAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts no
# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
#IgnoreRhosts yes

# To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!
#PasswordAuthentication yes
PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with
# some PAM modules and threads)
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes
#KerberosGetAFSToken no

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes
#GSSAPIStrictAcceptorCheck yes
#GSSAPIKeyExchange no

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
UsePAM yes

#AllowAgentForwarding yes
#AllowTcpForwarding yes
#GatewayPorts no
X11Forwarding yes
#X11DisplayOffset 10
#X11UseLocalhost yes
#PermitTTY yes
PrintMotd no
#PrintLastLog yes
#TCPKeepAlive yes
#PermitUserEnvironment no
#Compression delayed
#ClientAliveInterval 0
#ClientAliveCountMax 3
#UseDNS no
#PidFile /var/run/sshd.pid
#MaxStartups 10:30:100
#PermitTunnel no
#ChrootDirectory none
#VersionAddendum none

# no default banner path
#Banner none

# Allow client to pass locale environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem       sftp    /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
#       X11Forwarding no
#       AllowTcpForwarding no
#       PermitTTY no
#       ForceCommand cvs server
PermitRootLogin no


@ThomasWard Oh wow (facepalm), thank you so much. Everything works as intended now.

Converted to an answer, please mark that as accepted.

authorized_keys is a file not a directory.
Copy the contents of your id_rsa.pub file into the authorized_keys FILE on your remote server in the target user's .ssh folder in their home space.  If authorized_keys exists as a directory on the remote, remove the directory and its contents, and create a file and start appending public keys on new lines to the file.

Note that it is not advised to use the root account directly even via SSH.  It's suggested you create a new user with sudo privileges, or use the on-installation created user account instead of the root account for interacting with your server.

Wouldn’t using ssh-copy-id from the client be another effective way of doing the same thing?

@mpboden except that they indicated they created a directory and stored data there. Also, ssh-copy-id would require remote login, and the root login is only permitted with passwordless auth, so it wouldn't work specifically in OP's use case.  Answer was written to be for "any user", but OP was trying to make it work for root user.

Yeah, I saw that about the directory. It would work if it was a standard user and directory was deleted first. I guess the real question is why root login vs user login with sudo privileges? But that’s a different topic.

@mpboden Yep, it is.
